# Receiving reply intent data from Android Wear notification reply

Tags: android, wear-os, voice-recognition

I'm trying to get the voice reply example working on my Android Wear app (https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/voice-input.html). I am never getting the results into my reply activity.

My code for the MainActivity is here:

```
package com.example.android.basicnotifications;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.RemoteInput;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * The entry point to the BasicNotification sample.
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * A numeric value that identifies the notification that we'll be sending.
     * This value needs to be unique within this app, but it doesn't need to be
     * unique system-wide.
     */
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sample_layout);

    }

    /**
     * Send a sample notification using the NotificationCompat API.
     */

    public static final String EXTRA_VOICE_REPLY = "extra_voice_reply";
    public void sendNotification(View view) {

        String replyLabel = getResources().getString( R.string.reply_label );

        String []replyChoices = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.reply_choices);

        RemoteInput remoteInput = new RemoteInput.Builder( EXTRA_VOICE_REPLY )
            .setLabel( replyLabel )
                .setChoices( replyChoices )
            .build();


        Intent replyIntent = new Intent( this, ReplyActivity.class );
        PendingIntent replyPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, replyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );

        NotificationCompat.Action action = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder( android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email,
                getString( R.string.label ), replyPendingIntent )
                .addRemoteInput(remoteInput)
                .build();

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_input_add)
//                .setLargeIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_dialer)
                .setContentTitle( "The title of the notification")
                .setContentText( "The text for the notification")
                .extend( new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender().addAction( action ))
                .build();

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getApplicationContext());
        int notificationId = 1000;
        notificationManager.notify( notificationId, notification );

    }

}
```

The ReplyActivity is here:

```
package com.example.android.basicnotifications;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.RemoteInput;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Created by cdawson on 11/14/16.
 */
public class ReplyActivity extends Activity{

    private CharSequence getMessageText( Intent intent ) {
        Bundle remoteInput = RemoteInput.getResultsFromIntent(intent);
        if (remoteInput != null) {
            return remoteInput.getCharSequence(MainActivity.EXTRA_VOICE_REPLY);
        }
        else {
            return "";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sample_layout);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        CharSequence cs = getMessageText( intent );

        Log.v( "ReplyActivity", cs.toString() );
//        CharSequence cs = getMessageText(savedInstanceState);


    }

}
```

Specifically, I'm unsure where I call the function `getMessageText()` . Inside the `ReplyActivity`? When the `PendingIntent` is resolved (is that the correct terminology?) I imagine the app should launch into that activity, but I'm unclear how that happens when the reply is initiated by the wear side of things (it seems strange to launch an entire new activity and UI on the Android device when a reply is made from the watch).

Comment: Why are you using `PendingIntent.getActivity` in the first place?

Comment: I am using Pending Intent because it was in the example. Should I not use that?

Comment: No, I was wondering why you wanted to load an Activity to handle the Direct Reply, rather than use `PendingIntent.getService()` to start a service